# the use of " in more recent years..."

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

Is this sentence correct?

> **In more recent years**, she’s been teaching English for academic
>   purposes to undergraduates at the university of Iowa.

Comment: Proofreading questions are I'm afraid off topic on this site. Please visit this page: english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Generally speaking, questions that show research, and whose answer cannot be found in any online dictionary will always attract upvotes, attention and *good* answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. It's not really any different to if you were to replace "in more recent years" with "recently".

Comment: "Recently,..." would be preferred because it is simple and direct.

Comment: so whether it is " Recently" or " In more recent years...", it should be followed by the perfect tense. Whats the difference between saying " Recently she has taught..." vs " Recently she has been teaching..."?

Comment: @yanni please edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, but English does not have an imperfect tense. _She has been_ is present perfect.